# Android MessageDigest NoSuchAlgorithmException after calling JNI Function

Tags: android, exception, cryptography, java-native-interface

Problem Description: 
NoSuchAlgorithmException is thrown when calling function

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
```

after calling some JNI Code which I will attach later.

The weird thing happens when I test the code on a real smart Android phone (Sony Ericsson X10i, Android 2.3.7) and an Android emulator (Android 2.3.3)

if I call getInstance(..) function before the JNI code, everything is fine. But if i run JNI code first and then getInstance(..) function, a NoSuchAlgorithmException is thrown.

However this is not the most weird thing. If I test the code in an android emulator (Android 4.2), everything is good no matter how i call the function and the JNI codes.

I guess it is the problem of Android version. But i don't know why the calling order matters
(i don't do anything about MessageDigest in the JNI code). Anyone has any clue about this problem?

The Code I use for calling MessageDigest to get the MD5 Hash Code for a certain file:

```
            MessageDigest digest = null;
......
            try {
                digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                ........
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Then comes the Jni Code ,which is used to get the public key of a signed .apk file. The basic idea is using JNI to call Java methods.

```
    jobject getpackageManagerObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject context_object) {

    //Get class of Context Object
    jclass context_class = env->GetObjectClass(context_object);
    jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(context_class, "getPackageManager",
                "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
    jobject package_manager = env->CallObjectMethod(context_object, methodId);
    return package_manager;
    }  

    jobject getAllPackageInfo(JNIEnv* env, jobject package_manager_object) {

    //Get all installed packages Information, make a java call getInstalledPackages(...)
    jclass pack_manager_class = env->GetObjectClass(package_manager_object);
    jclass pack_manager_static_class = env->FindClass(
                    "android/content/pm/PackageManager");

    jfieldID field_signatures = env->GetStaticFieldID(pack_manager_static_class,
                    "GET_SIGNATURES", "I");
    int get_signatures_value = env->GetStaticIntField(pack_manager_static_class,
                    field_signatures);
    jmethodID methodId = NULL;
    methodId = env->GetMethodID(pack_manager_class, "getInstalledPackages",
                    "(I)Ljava/util/List;");
    jobject list_package_object = env->CallObjectMethod(package_manager_object,
                    methodId, get_signatures_value);
    return list_package_object;
    }

    jobject getIterator(JNIEnv* env, jobject list_package_object) {

    //make a java call to get List.Iterator()
    jclass list_class = env->GetObjectClass(list_package_object);
    jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(list_class, "iterator",
                "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");
    jobject iterator = env->CallObjectMethod(list_package_object, methodId);
    return iterator;
    }

    JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_jni_classes_JniClasses_getSign(
        JNIEnv *env, jclass jcl, jobject context_object,
        jstring str_package_name) {

    log_print("Call getSign()");
    log_print(env->GetStringUTFChars(str_package_name, NULL));

    jobject package_manager_object = NULL;
    package_manager_object = getpackageManagerObject(env, context_object);
    if (package_manager_object != NULL) {
        log_print("Get PackageManager Successfully!");
    } else {
        log_print("Get PackageManager Failed!");
        return NULL;
    }

    //Get all installed packages Information, make a java call getInstalledPackages(...)
    jobject list_package_object = NULL;
    list_package_object = getAllPackageInfo(env, package_manager_object);
    if (list_package_object != NULL) {
        log_print("Get All Package Info Successfully!");
    } else {
        log_print("Get Package Info Failed!");
        return NULL;
    }

    jobject iterator = getIterator(env, list_package_object);
    if (iterator != NULL) {
        log_print("Get iterator Successfully!");
    } else {
        log_print("Get iterator Failed!");
        return NULL;
    }

    //get the signature from the package
    jclass iterator_class = env->GetObjectClass(iterator);
    jmethodID methodId_for_hasNext = env->GetMethodID(iterator_class, "hasNext",
            "()Z");
    jmethodID methodId_for_next = env->GetMethodID(iterator_class, "next",
            "()Ljava/lang/Object;");

    /*if (methodId_for_next != NULL) {
    log_print("Get methodId_for_next Successfully!");
    } else {
    log_print("Get methodId_for_next Failed!");
    return NULL;
    }*/

    while (env->CallBooleanMethod(iterator, methodId_for_hasNext)) {
    jobject package_info = env->CallObjectMethod(iterator,
                methodId_for_next);
    jclass package_info_class = env->GetObjectClass(package_info);
    jfieldID fieldId_packageNname = env->GetFieldID(package_info_class,
                "packageName", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring package_name = (jstring) env->GetObjectField(package_info,
                fieldId_packageNname);
    const char * c_package_name = env->GetStringUTFChars(package_name,NULL);
    const char * c_str_package_name = env->GetStringUTFChars(
                str_package_name, NULL);
    log_print("Start comparing ");
    log_print(c_package_name);

    //Two Package names is the same
    if (!strcmp(c_package_name, c_str_package_name)) {
    log_print("Same Package Name Found!!!");
    jfieldID field_package_signatures = env->GetFieldID(package_info_class,    
                            "signatures","[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
    if (field_package_signatures != NULL) {
        log_print("Get field_package_signatures Successfully!");
            } else {
                log_print("Get field_package_signatures Failed!");
                return NULL;
            }

        jobjectArray signature_array = NULL;
        signature_array = (jobjectArray) env->GetObjectField(package_info,
                    field_package_signatures);

        if (signature_array != NULL) {
            log_print("Get signature_array Successfully!");
        } else {
            log_print("Get signature_array Failed!");
            return NULL;
        }
        jobject signature_object = env->GetObjectArrayElement(
                    signature_array, 0);
        jclass signature_class = env->GetObjectClass(signature_object);
        jmethodID methodId_for_toByteArray = env->GetMethodID(
                    signature_class, "toByteArray", "()[B");
        jbyteArray signature_info = NULL;
        signature_info = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(
                    signature_object, methodId_for_toByteArray);

        if (signature_info != NULL) {
            log_print("Get signature_info byte array Successfully!");
        } else {
            log_print("Get signature_info byte array Failed!");
            return NULL;
        }
        return signature_info;
    }

        env->DeleteLocalRef(package_info);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(package_info_class);

    }    
//don't find any package that matches str_package_name
    return NULL;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_jni_classes_JniClasses_getPublicKey(
        JNIEnv *env, jclass jcl, jbyteArray sig_bytes) {

    jclass cert_factory_class = env->FindClass(
            "java/security/cert/CertificateFactory");
    jmethodID methodId_getInstance = env->GetStaticMethodID(cert_factory_class,
            "getInstance",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/security/cert/CertificateFactory;");
    jstring encode = env->NewStringUTF("X.509");
    jobject cert_factory_object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(
            cert_factory_class, methodId_getInstance);
    jmethodID methodId_generateCertificate = env->GetMethodID(
            cert_factory_class, "generateCertificate",
            "(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/security/cert/Certificate;");

    //Get ByteArrayInputStream Object

    jclass byteArrayInputStream_class = env->FindClass(
            "java/io/ByteArrayInputStream");
    jmethodID methodId_constructor = env->GetMethodID(
            byteArrayInputStream_class, "<init>", "([B)V");
    jobject byteArrayInputStream_object = env->NewObject(
            byteArrayInputStream_class, methodId_constructor, sig_bytes);

   //Get X509Certificate Object

    jobject x509Certificate_object = env->CallObjectMethod(cert_factory_object,
            methodId_generateCertificate, byteArrayInputStream_object);

   //Get PublicKey

    jclass x509Certificate_class = env->GetObjectClass(x509Certificate_object);
    jmethodID methodId_getPublicKey = env->GetMethodID(x509Certificate_class,
            "getPublicKey", "()Ljava/security/PublicKey;");
    jobject publicKey_object = env->CallObjectMethod(x509Certificate_object,
            methodId_getPublicKey);
    jclass publicKey_class = env->GetObjectClass(publicKey_object);

    jmethodID methodId_toString = env->GetMethodID(publicKey_class, "toString",
            "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring str_publicKey = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(publicKey_object,
            methodId_toString);
    return str_publicKey;
}
```

Comment: What does the JNI code do that you cannot do in Java?

Comment: If you go out of the Java managed runtime there is no such thing as memory protection anymore. Anything that overrides memory of the running process is vulnerable... Make sure you buffer/pointer handling code is up to scratch...

Comment: I cannot get MD5 MessageDigest Instance Object

Comment: This was very helpful.  We were trying to do something vaguely similar and this code helped tremendously.

Comment: Has this been resolved by now? If so could you post an answer? This is one of the top unanswered questions for cryptography!

Comment: I've voted this as "too broad" as it would require debugging on a local system to answer the question, or an online debugging session to answer it.